# How to compute in the text box from the computed value from combobox and numericupdown

Tags: c#

I have my basic pay that is computed from the Basic Pay (The position code with a value ex. Code: A, Rate/day: 500) multiplied by the No of days worked.

```
if (cmbPositionCode.SelectedItem == "A")
                txtBasic.Text = (500 * nudDays.Value).ToString();
            
            else if (cmbPositionCode.SelectedItem == "B")
                txtBasic.Text = (400 * nudDays.Value).ToString();
            
            else
                txtBasic.Text = (300 * nudDays.Value).ToString();
```

And now, I need to compute for the SSS Contribution that is if the basic pay is within the given range (ex. 10,000 & above, SSS Rate is 7%).

SSS Contribution = Basic Pay * SSS Rate

I tried this but I was not really sure on how to do it

```
            double sscontri;
            sscontri = Convert.ToDouble(txtBasic);
            
            if (txtBasic >= 10000)
                
                sscontri = txtBasic * 0.07;
                txtSSS.Text = sscontri.ToString();
```

I'm getting an error of **Operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type** and **Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type**

I need help on how to remove this errors. Is my txtBasic inside the if wrong? TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I'm getting an error of Operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type and Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type*

Because you can't compare `txtBasic` which is a ***control*** to `10000` which is ***int***. If you want to compare the `txtBasic text`, you should convert it first to an int:

```
int basic = int.Parse(txtBasic.Text);
if (basic >= 10000)
    sscontri = txtBasic * 0.07;
    txtSSS.Text = sscontri.ToString();
```

Comment: I tried it and it still gave me the same error in the (txtBasic >= 10000) and txtBasic * 0.07;

Comment: Oh @Spooderman, I forgot to put the right value in the right part of the else

Comment: I tried this code

`//SSS CONTRIBUTION//
   
   int basic = int.Parse(txtBasic.Text);
   
   if (basic >= 10000)
   {
    double sscontri = basic * 0.07;
    txtSSS.Text = sscontri.ToString();
   }

`

But the answer is not showing up on the textbox txtSSS